# Large number of host emulation

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cloud, vmware

What would be the best way to emulate (or really to instantiate) a large number of hosts / virtual machines / docker containers in the cloud?

Assume I want to run a scenario where 10,000 hosts are running the same application. Is there a cloud service which provides the ability to  "clone" a single host to 10K instances? Is there a way to configure slight changes in those hosts (in terms of Geo location / IP / hostname / MAC address)?

Answer (score 6):

you create a Docker Swarm stack file:

```
---
version: '3.1'

services:   
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu # or your custom Docker image
      deploy:
        replicas: 10000
```

Then, with `docker stack` you can run your 10000 Ubuntu's on one or - probably better in this case - a set of Swarm hosts. This could be bare metal or AWS. Enjoy!

For MAC address is very interesting question which I hope other colleagues here can answer. Geolocation should be no problem as this is AFAIK a system setting - virtual OS does not implement a physical GPS sensor.

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) give an example how to set a fixed MAC address on `docker run` - possibly this can be translated to the stack YML file as well.

```
docker run --mac-address=".." ...
```